# NullPointerException while trying to replace a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am getting a javga.lang.NullPointerException while trying to replace a Fragment in my Activity. I use a FrameLayout as my host for the fragment to be placed in dynamically based on button clicks.

Exception Stacktrace:

```
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: com.data3s.eluzzionnative, PID: 1595
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.NullPointerException
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:653)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
[AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[Process] Sending signal. PID: 1595 SIG: 9
```

Here's the code I am using to replace the fragment.

```
_myWorkView = new MyWorkFragment();
_myWorkView.ViewModel = myWorkVm;
var trans = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
trans.Replace(Resource.Id.myWorkView, _myWorkView);
trans.Commit();
```

A thing to note is, if I try to place-in the fragment in Activity's onCreate, it works perfectly fine. The exception is only happening when I try to place-in the fragment from OnOptionsItemSelected (i.e. a tap on the IMenuItem)

Is there something which I am doing wrong? Let me know if some more info is needed.

Thanks.

EDIT:

The problem was in a preceding code and not related to above snippet at all. Sorry.

Comment: why you are assigning _myWorkView = myWorkVm; here?

Comment: Have you tried it using `ChildFragmentManager` ?

Comment: @Nag sorry.. its actually _myWorkView.ViewModel.. updated the questions... Its an mvvmcross app

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am not placing it in a child fragment.. the fragment is being placed in an Activity.

Comment: @MohibSheth: When using `add` instead of `replace` then?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK same thing. Exact same exception when using add too

Comment: Have you tried using getFragmentManager() instead of the static method form FragmentManager?

Comment: You can refere [This Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625526/fragments-how-to-use-them-with-activities-that-require-actions/28625911#28625911

This will help you to find mistake

Comment: @programmer23 this is in C# using Xamarin.Android and not java.. internally FragmentManager does getFragmentManager itself ;)

Comment: @BSavaliya Am, isn't my code very same as that example. Could you point me to the exact mistake of mine?

Comment: @programmer23 `FragmentManager` is a wrapper around `getFragmentManager()` in Xamarin.Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a preceding code and not related to above snippet at all. Sorry.